# run a script and return system to suspended or running mode

Tags: suspend, cron

Somehow I cannot find how to do this common task.
I want to run a (backup) script daily at certain time regardless whether the system is running or suspended and return to the previous state afterwards.
I played with `rtcwake` and I have two major problems:

1. I cannot tell if the system was woken up manually or by `rtcwake`
2. It seems that if I resume the system manually, it forgets about `rtcwake` wake-up

Comment: That the system forgets about rtc wakup is an advantage I think, then you can include the return to suspend in the "after rtcwakeup" -script. How do you run the script right now? (cron / other script, do you use rsync etc) And what is your rtc command?

Comment: At this moment I just run my script manually.<br>

Comment: I respect your opinion, but nonetheless I have a different scenario that I'd like to use<br>

Comment: I want to run the script automatically at certain time daily, preferably at the night when the machine is idle. It can be either suspended or alive and I want the script to run and return the system to its previous state.

Comment: And what is 'after rtcwakeup' script? It seems that scripts in /etc/pm/sleep.d and /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d are not being run on every wakeup.

Comment: That is not what I mean, you can make the rtcwake command include a (your) script. But again: what is the rtcwake command you use? I am not sure I understand the comments above: did someone remove comments or are those you posted above to me? (could you ping me if you comment to me?)

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, here is what I use:     sudo rtcwake -m mem -l -t $(date +%s -d 'today 16:50')     I think I found how to do it.

Comment: 1. set crontab to run bkup at certain moment   <br />

Comment: Sorry, somehow formatting does not work for me.
@Jacob Vlijm, Let me know what you think:
Set crontab:
* * * * * sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t $(date +%s -d 'tomorrow 00:30') > /dev/null 2>&1
0 31 * * * sudo backup > /dev/null 2>&1
Now while the system is on, it refreshes wakeup time every minute. If the system is suspended 
when backup is scheduled, it wakes up by rtc.
There is a problem if the system is on between midnight and 0:30, but I think I can live with it.

Comment: I am not sure what the construction is :), but why not have the rtcwake command run at a fixed time (since it is ignored when the system is awake) and include `&& <your_backup_command> && <go_to_sleep_again_command>`. If you set the regular backup (from cron, runs if the system is awake) just before wake-uptime, either one is executed, but never both, and with two simple commands.

Answer (score 2):

A single `rtcwake` does not work because with `-m no` option the command after `&&` is being run immediately, not at wake time.
Anyway these two lines do the trick:

```
*/5 * * * * sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t $(date +\%s -d 'tomorrow 00:01')  
2 0 * * * /home/alex/perl/bkup/bkup.pl
```